# Angular How to define multiple observe in http post

Tags: angular, http, post

Good morning,
In a Http post call I need to read in the answer both the header and the events in order to manage a progression during the call.
To manage the progression I set observe : 'events' and it works perfectly.
I need to set also observe: 'response' to read the header of the answer.
how can i do it?

```
 return this.http.post(ip + this.apiDownFile,JSON.stringify(paramObj),{
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    }).pipe(
        map(risposta=>risposta)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to observe the response in addition.
You can reach the response if you are observing 'events' as the response is part of the events you should be receiving.

If you want to do something with the response, add rxjs `tap` operator and there check whether the event is an HTTP Response.
You can do that by provided `enum` which angular gives - `HttpEventType`.

**import:**

```js
import { HttpEventType } from "@angular/common/http";
```

**Code:**

```js
return this.http.post(ip + this.apiDownFile,JSON.stringify(paramObj),{
  headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  responseType: 'blob' as 'json',
  reportProgress: true,
  observe: 'events'
}).pipe(
  map(risposta=>risposta),
  tap(risposta => {
    if(risposta === HttpEventType.Response) {
      // do something
    }
  })
)
```